# How to stub/spy external methods in a module that are called internally?

Tags: node.js, sinon

```
//entity module    
function isUnique(name) {
   return true;
}
exports.isUnique = isUnique;

function create(name) {
  if (isUnique(name)) { return console.log(name); }
  else { return new Error(); }
}    
exports.create = create;
```

Is it possible to stub the "isUnique" method to change the behavior of the "create" method?

```
var entity = require("./entity");
var sinon = require("sinon");
var assert = require("assert");

var stub = sinon.stub(entity, "isUnique", function (name) { return false });

entity.create("test");
stub.restore();
assert(stub.calledOnce, true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: no.

Your module holds two references to the `isUnique` function: one from the function declaration itself, and one assigned to `exports.isUnique`.

The `create` function is using the first, but Sinon is stubbing the second.

For the stub to get called, `create` needs to use the reference that gets stubbed:

```
if (exports.isUnique(name)) { return console.log(name); }
// `this.isUnique` also works, because `this` === `module.exports`
```

Alternatively, you can use a module like [`rewire`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire).

Comment: Okay. That is kind of what I was thinking was happening as well. Thank you for the input. The entity module is "external" so it can't be modified. I will have to look into rewire.